# Calling a column from csv.file to extract its data

Tags: r

I imported the csv file that I want to use in r. Here, I am trying to call one of the columns from the csv file. This column has a list of urls titled "URLs". Then, I want the code which I have to scrap data from each url. In short, I want to use more efficient way than listing all the urls in c() function since I have about 200 links.

https://www.nytimes.com/2018/04/07/health/health-care-mergers-doctors.html?rref=collection%2Fsectioncollection%2Fhealth
https://www.nytimes.com/2018/04/11/well/move/why-exercise-alone-may-not-be-the-key-to-weight-loss.html?rref=collection%2Fsectioncollection%2Fhealth
https://www.nytimes.com/2018/04/07/health/antidepressants-withdrawal-prozac-cymbalta.html?rref=collection%2Fsectioncollection%2Fhealth
https://www.nytimes.com/2018/04/09/well/why-you-should-get-the-new-shingles-vaccine.html?rref=collection%2Fsectioncollection%2Fhealth
https://www.nytimes.com/2018/04/09/health/fda-essure-bayer-contraceptive-implant.html?rref=collection%2Fsectioncollection%2Fhealth
https://www.nytimes.com/2018/04/09/health/hot-pepper-thunderclap-headaches.html?rref=collection%2Fsectioncollection%2Fhealth

The error appears when running this: `article <- links %>% map(read_html)`.

It gives me this message:

```
(Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : 
no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "factor")
```

Here is the code:

```
setwd("C:/Users/Majed/Desktop")

d <- read.csv("NYT.csv")

d

links<- d$URLs

article <- links %>% map(read_html)

title <-
  article %>% map_chr(. %>% html_node("title") %>% html_text())

content <-
  article %>% map_chr(. %>% html_nodes(".story-body-text") %>% html_text() %>% paste(., collapse = ""))

article_table <- data.frame("Title" = title, "Content" = content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the meaning of your error message: `read_html` expects a character string, but you're giving it a factor. `read.csv` converts strings to factors, unless you include the argument `stringsAsFactors = F`. `read_csv` from `readr` is a good alternative if you, like me, forget that you don't want strings automatically turned into factors.

I can't reproduce the problem without your data, but try converting the URLs to strings:

```
links <- as.character(d$URLs)

article <- links %>% map(read_html)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this however the second line is not executing. It take so long and no action comes out of it.

Comment: You'll need to include at least some of your data for anyone to try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I included some of the urls in the post.

Comment: This doesn't tell me what your data looks like. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for how to make a reproducible question. That way it will be easier for us to help you.